# Angular 5 navigation from one module component to another module component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have home component in homeModule and contactUs componenent in contactModule.

When I click cancel in contactUs component, it should redirect us to Home.

routes

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {homeComponent} from './home/home.component';


const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'home', component: homeComponent},
{ path: 'demo-ui/home', component: homeComponent},
];


@NgModule({
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
],
exports: [RouterModule],
declarations: []
})
export class AppHomeRoutingModule {
}
```

I tried the following code but it didnt work

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormsModule, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';


 @Component({
   //some code
 })
export class contactUsComponent implements OnInit {
constructor( private router: Router ){
}

ngOnInit() {
}


redirect(){
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');    }

}
 //html
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  (click)="redirect()"> 
  Cancel </button>
```

Also, I tried

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  [routerLink]="['/home']"> Cancel </button>
```

and

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  routerLink="/home"> Cancel </button>
```

Error:  Cannot match any routes. URL Segment './home'

Comment: Hope you have import `AppHomeRoutingModule` into your `AppModule`.

Comment: yes I did import AppHomeRoutingModule in homeModule. We do not have common/shared module for the application

Comment: Are homeComponent and contactUsComponent part of same module?

Comment: No, they are not. "I have home component in homeModule and contactUs componenent in contactModule"

Comment: Have you imported RouterModule to contactModule also?

Comment: routerModule as in " AppHomeRoutingModule" (routing of home component)  in contactUs Module?

Comment: @ShivangGupta : thanks I imported AppHomeRoutingModule in contactUs module. It resolved initial issue. 
Url is changed, however page is not redirected. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You have to only add the RouterModule dependency in contactModule. Importing AppHomeRoutingModule in contactModule is not required. You can share the screen with me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180222/discussion-between-beginner-and-shivang-gupta).

Comment: Was this solved finally? How about posting the final solution as an answer and marking it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use an anchor tag for `routerLink` to work.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" routerLink="/home">Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create function in your .ts

Like this :

```
redirectToHome(){
   this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

and call into your html

```
<button (click)="redirectToHome()">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use this : this.router.navigate(['home']);

Comment: constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

  } you added Router in the constructor ??

Comment: Yes, I did. "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment 'home'" this is the error I am receiving. I don't think there's anything wrong with the imports